# Fuseki update does not appear to be working in version 4.6.1

Tags: sparql, jena, fuseki

I'm looking to incorporate Fuseki into a project where I need to update a graph, but so far I have not been able to get it to work.  To demonstrate this issue, I created a dataset using [example 5 from the W3 SPARQL 1.1 standard document](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#deleteInsert).

The dataset `w3_update_example_5.ttl` (from the standard):

```
# Graph: http://example/addresses
@prefix foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .

<http://example/president25> foaf:givenName "Bill" .
<http://example/president25> foaf:familyName "McKinley" .
<http://example/president27> foaf:givenName "Bill" .
<http://example/president27> foaf:familyName "Taft" .
<http://example/president42> foaf:givenName "Bill" .
<http://example/president42> foaf:familyName "Clinton" .
```

The update request, `w3_update_example_5.rq` (from the standard):

```
PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

WITH <http://example/addresses>
DELETE { ?person foaf:givenName 'Bill' }
INSERT { ?person foaf:givenName 'William' }
WHERE
  { ?person foaf:givenName 'Bill'
  }
```

I start Fuseki with the following command line:

```
$ ../tmp/apache-jena-fuseki-4.6.1/fuseki-server --update --verbose --file w3_update_example_5.ttl --localhost /w3_update_example_5
```

I submit this request via `s-update`:

```
$ s-update --service=http://localhost:3030/w3_update_example_5/update --update=w3_update_example_5.rq
```

The server appears to receive the request correctly, but the it returns a `204 No Content` status and does not update the graph.  The verbose logs from the server for this request:

```
09:56:32 INFO  Fuseki          :: [2] POST http://localhost:3030/w3_update_example_5/update
09:56:32 INFO  Fuseki          :: [2]   => User-Agent:          SOH/Fuseki 1.0.0
09:56:32 INFO  Fuseki          :: [2]   => Host:                localhost:3030
09:56:32 INFO  Fuseki          :: [2]   => Content-Length:      205
09:56:32 INFO  Fuseki          :: [2]   => Content-Type:        application/sparql-update
09:56:32 INFO  Fuseki          :: [2] Update = PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>  WITH <http://example/addresses> DELETE { ?person foaf:givenName 'Bill' } INSERT { ?person foaf:givenName 'William' } WHERE   { ?person foaf:givenName 'Bill'   } 
09:56:32 INFO  Fuseki          :: [2] 204 No Content (23 ms)
```

After this request, the Fuseki web UI shows the graph has not changed.

I can edit the graph using the web UI, but when I look at the network traffic, it seems to just send the entire graph back to the server.  I don't want to do this.  I need to be able to manipulate individual triples in the graph.

Jena has been around long enough that I would expect this to "just work". What am I doing wrong or is this a problem with the server?

I have not had any issues with submitting queries to the server, assuming I have the query correct.

Comment: Could you show how you loaded the data? The Update has a WITH clause. If the data is loaded into the named graph http://example/addresses, the example works for me.

Comment: It is loaded when I start the server via the --file argument.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the WITH clause.  If I change it to 'WITH <http://localhost:3030/w3_update_example_5/>', it now responds with a status code of 200 and indicates success, but when I query it, nothing has changed.
```$ curl -XPOST -d "query=PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> SELECT ?person ?pred ?obj WHERE { ?person foaf:givenName 'Bill' . ?person ?pred ?obj . }&format=csv" http://localhost:3030/w3_update_example_5/query
person,pred,obj
http://example/president27,http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/givenName,Bill
...
```

Comment: `--file` loads a Turtle file into the default graph, not a named graph. Try without the WITH line.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [AndyS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/757100/andys) for guidance.  Once I removed the WITH line, it worked!

The corrected query:

```
PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

DELETE { ?person foaf:givenName 'Bill' }
INSERT { ?person foaf:givenName 'William' }
WHERE
  { ?person foaf:givenName 'Bill'
  }
```